# Why are 10k resistors chosen after the LED on the CHRG and FAULT pins?

Tags: circuit-analysis, led, resistors

Would someone care to explain why 10k resistors were chosen to be placed after the two LEDs near the CHRG and FAULT pins? I have looked at the documentation (linked below) and could not find an explanation for this. I have a very basic circuits understanding and the only logical conclusion I can come to is that they were chosen to not blow out the LED / to limit the current, but was confused why it was specifically 10k and not another value.

Is there any particular reason that 10k was chosen opposed to a different value? Is it just the most efficient at protecting the LED and the most common LED that fits that ohm range? Any help would be greatly appreciated, thank you.

[image: LT3652 Circuit]

[LT3652 Data Sheet](https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/3652fe.pdf)

Comment: The datasheet you linked states that the CHRG and FAULT pins can sink up to 10mA, so it protects the chip as much as the LEDs. 10k is just a suggested value, make them lower if you want the LEDs brighter.

Comment: look up a video or page describing "choosing a resistor of LED"; there's a lot of good explanations out there.

Answer (score 3):

Those resistors limit the current through the LEDs to protect both the LEDs and the IC from excessive current.

10 K will limit the current to about 1 mA - I would probably try 3 to 5 K to make the LEDs a little brighter.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation Peter! That's what I was guessing the answer was but I was still unsure. Thank you for the clarification.